# Multiple file send to server using Retrofit 2.0.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.0 for api parsing. I send `multiple image files`, Document files,Audio files to server and  got the exception like

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: `@Part` annotation must supply a name or use `MultipartBody.Part` parameter type. (parameter #2)

API Service Calls

```
   @Multipart
    @POST("save-portfolio")
    Call<ResponseBody> savePortfolio(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, 
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part[] images,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part[] doc,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part[] audio, 
                                     @Part("userid") RequestBody userid, 
                                     @Part("portfolio_id") RequestBody portfolio_id,
                                     @Part("tags") RequestBody tag,
                                     @Part("video") RequestBody video,
                                     @Part("title") RequestBody title,
                                     @Part("description") RequestBody description);

  Call<ResponseBody> loginRequestCall = service.savePortfolio(authorization,imgbody,docbody,audiobody,userid,portfolio_id,tag,video,title,description);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> update the latest version of your retrofit library